# exponential equation in in c#

Tags: python, c#, complex-numbers, exponential

I try to convert some python files to C#, the problem is I used the same method in C# but my results are different from what I got in Matlab and Python.
my python equation is :

```py
data VM :[1,1,1,1] VA : [1,0,0,0]

V0  = bus[:, VM] * exp(1j * pi/180 * bus[:, VA])
```

and my C# code is :

```cs
// nb = number of bus = 4

Vector<System.Numerics.Complex> V0 = Vector<System.Numerics.Complex>.Build.Dense(nb);
           
// ## initial state
for (int i = 0; i < busList.Count(); i++)
{
    V0[i] = (busList[i].VM) * System.Numerics.Complex.Exp((Math.PI / 180) *
            (busList[i].VA));
}
```

the result for python is :

```
[0.9998477+0.01745241j 1.       +0.j         1.       +0.j, 1.       +0.j        ]
```

the result in C# is :

```
(1.01761, 0)
      (1, 0)
      (1, 0)
      (1, 0)
```

Comment: I also try to create my complex var like :


 System.Numerics.Complex  test = new System.Numerics.Complex( 1, (Math.PI / 180) * (busList[i].VA));

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, everyone. I got my answer

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < busList.Count(); i++)
{
    System.Numerics.Complex Cal_v0 = new System.Numerics.Complex(Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * (busList[i].VA)), Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180) * (busList[i].VA));
    V0[i] = (busList[i].VM) * Cal_v0;

    Console.WriteLine("V0 = " + V0[i].Real + " + " + V0[i].Imaginary + "i");
}
```